# object is not execute __del__

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create a object from a array when a new port is opened en delete it when it is closet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import thread
import psutil
import time
thelist = []

class connection:
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
         print "open van stream"  + str(self.name)

     def __del__(self):
         print "close van stream "

def contains(list, filter):
     for x in list:
         if filter(x):
             return True
     return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
         PROCNAME = "tvheadend"
         for proc in psutil.process_iter():
             if proc.name == PROCNAME:
                 process = proc
         if not process:
             print "not found tvheadend"
             exit()
         print "Found " + str(process)

         while(1):
             for list in process.get_connections(kind='udp'):

                 if not contains(thelist, lambda x: x.name == list.local_address[0]):
                    thelist.append(connection(list.local_address[0]))

             for list in thelist:
                 print thelist
                 if not contains(process.get_connections(kind='udp'), lambda x: x.local_address[0] == list.name):
                     thelist.remove(list)
                     print "removed"
             time.sleep(0.5)

     except SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt:
         exit()
```

but it only prints "close van stream" when i open a new one. not when i close one. With the "print thelist" function i can see that the object is removed from the array but it does not print "close van stream"

Answer (score 0):

As long as you still reference it from `list`, it is not gone.

It is only gone as soon as you re-assign `list`.

Only then will the reference counter of this object drop to 0 and `__del__` will be called.

BTW, it is a bad idea to call a variable `list`, because this shadows the built-in type `list`.

And, BTW, `__del__` [should not be relied on](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__). Instead, you should consider to define and use a context manager.

EDIT: The context manager thing is obviously not possible here, but you should `.close()` it explicitly instead of relying on `__del__()` being called.